# How do I view or verify signed .mobileconfig files using Terminal?

Tags: macos, certificate, ssl, openssl

I need to troubleshoot problems with signed .mobileconfig profiles. How can I show the signature of a these files using Terminal? Is it also possible to verify the certificates that were used to sign the profile?

Is there a way to output the XML content of these files without the signature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple's .mobileconfig files are signed using PKCS7. The signing certificate data can be shown using the following command:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -print_certs -in ~/Settings.mobileconfig
```

You can copy/paste ASCII certificate data from the output into a plain text file (with a .cer filename extension) to create copies of the certificates:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIElTCCA32gAwIBAgIBAjALBgkqhkiG9w0BAQswga4xQDA+BgNVBAMMN0tlbGxl
eSBDb21wdXRpbmcgT3BlbiBEaXJlY3RvcnkgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3Jp
dHkxGTAXBgNVBAoMEEtlbGxleSBDb21wdXRpbmcxJTAjBgNVBAsMHE1BQ09TWCBP
...
q19fbG33zNwRhVHceYMpcbWG1MSqLxnPu4wo75OZFIJCaByZykfpKAzRZl9aa7rD
5bAuzZAziXBW7WWKce2a4hGN804W9RHco5HIGLsQAdg4pLZvENXF1+JNHtBVXjjL
WJrCDKjnCyS1DqmJqijk9KIDM8gP6iLLeQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

OpenSSL can be used to verify the code-signing certificate as well. Assuming that we've copied the signing CA's certificate text/data into `~/CA.crt`, and copied the code signing certificate into `~/CodeSigner.crt`.:

```
openssl verify -CAfile ~/CA.crt ~/CodeSigner.crt
```

Removing the signature from a file can be accomplished using this command:

```
openssl smime -inform DER -verify -in ~/Settings.mobileconfig -noverify -out ~/Unsigned.mobileconfig
```